# Inject SignalR Hub to Controller using net core error

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using asp net core *2.0* and new SignalR *1.0.0-alpha1-final* in my asp net core web api.

I am injecting SignalR hub (`LiveDataHandler`) to my controller (`DataController`)

```
public DataController(IOptions<TheAppSettings> config, ILogger<DataController> logger, LiveDataHandler liveDataHandler)
{
    // need to use data repository
    this.dataRepository = new DataRepository(config.Value.db);
}
```

and config to my SignalR Hub

```
public LiveDataHandler(IOptions<TheAppSettings> config)
{
    // need to use data repository
    this.dataRepository = new DataRepository(config.Value.db);
}
```

to setup signalR and setting I do

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // app settings to inject
    var theAppSettings = Configuration.GetSection("TheAppSettings");
    services.Configure<TheAppSettings>(theAppSettings);

    // Use WebSockets
    services.AddSignalR();

    ...
}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
     app.UseSignalR(routes =>
     {
         routes.MapHub<LiveDataHandler>("livedata");
     });

     ....
}
```

this compile with no problems, SignalR connects perfectly fine, but when I make a api call to my controller I'll get an error (sorry for the whole trace ...)

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'LoadingScreen.API.Hubs.LiveDataHandler' while attempting to activate 'LoadingScreen.API.Controllers.DataController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Now from the error I can roughly deduct that there is an issue with injecting the SignalR hub into the controller on instantiation, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Any ideas how to get arround this?

Before using SignalR, I was using WebSosketManager library, which use LiveDataHandler as service and injection worked with no problems:

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.MapWebSocketManager("/liveData", serviceProvider.GetService<LiveDataHandler>());
```

so I have only assumed, that signalR would work similiar way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code looks like you forgot to register dependencies needed for `IOptions<T>` resolving:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();

    // app settings to inject
    var theAppSettings = Configuration.GetSection("TheAppSettings");
    services.Configure<TheAppSettings>(theAppSettings);

    ...
 }
```